# Delete zero byte files write file name to text file

Tags: windows, command-line

I have the following in a batch script and it works for deleting all files of 0 byte size in the target directory but how can i modify it to append to a text file each file name only to a textfile called results.txt

```
set "targetdir=C:\Users\William\Desktop\test"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir/s/b/a-d "%targetdir%\*.*"') do ( if %%~Za equ 0 del "%%~a" )
```

so in results.txt i might see

somefilename.jpg

anotherfile.png

yetanotherfile.jpg

i've tried adding >results.txt to various parts of the script but no luck

Comment: A single `>` will continously empty the target file. Try `>>`, for appending.

Comment: i've tried >> and > and cannot get the filename to write to the results.txt

Comment: rather than `del "%%~a"`, your doing `echo "%%~a" >> results.txt`, right? If you're using `echo`, please update your question . Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set "targetdir=C:\Users\William\Desktop\test"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir/s/b/a-d "%targetdir%\*.*"') do ( if %%~Za equ 0 echo %%~na>>results.txt & del "%%~a")
```

try that :)